# How to edit a profile field from the node add form

Tags: nodes, users, forms

My client has a user field `field_geolocation` of type  Geofield.

And he has a content type `issue`, he allows people to create new issues (kinda like in drupal.org but private).

**What he wants is:** When someone is creating a new issue, he should be able to to set/edit the field in his profile identified by `field_geolocation`.

**My guess:** create a custom module which does the following

- Inject a widget for the user field `field_geolocation` inside the node add/edit form, prbably with FAPI
- Use Node API to save the data collected previously into the actual user.

Did I guess right? Or any better solutions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track.  It should be a pretty straight forward thing to implement.

I would add a custom submit handler to the node form for your issue content type.  Grab the submitted values for the geolocation field.  Load the user using `user_load()`, if the value has changed, the update it and call `user_save()`.